# How do you get rid of the automatic space added on a div within a td?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, css-tables

I have a simple table similar to this.

```
<table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <tr>
        <td style='border: 1px solid blue;'>
        <div style='background-color: yellow;'>
            test
        </div>
        <div style='background-color: green;'>
            test
        </div>
        </td>
        <td style='background-color: red; border: 1px solid blue;'>
            test
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This table generates this:

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of the space that is added between the yellow and green divs and the table border?

Comment: Just remove the padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That space is cell padding inserted by many (if not all) browsers by default, which you can easily remove:

```
<td style='border: 1px solid blue; padding: 0;'>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are not normalizing your CSS, browser applies some default `margin` and `padding` to some elements, inorder to reset those, here's a quick fix..

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/85Q8N/)

If you want to normalize your CSS in a more lenient way, than you can use [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your **CSS**

```
td {
    padding:0;   
}
```